Bookmark all open editor tabs to an existing bookmark in IntelliJ
In older versions of IntelliJ, it was possible to add all open tabs to an existing favorites list, which was quite convenient.
However, in the newer IntelliJ versions, the 'favorites' feature has been replaced by 'bookmarks.' While it's possible to add one tab at a time to an existing bookmark list or to create a new one for all open tabs, there's no option to add all open tabs to an existing bookmark. This simple UI feature would enhance user experience significantly. Personally, I organize tabs based on the tickets I'm working on, making it easy to navigate between them.
Has anyone had success or suggestions to improve my experience in the new 'bookmarks' feature?  I am trying to find a way to bookmark all open tabs to an existing list instead of creating a new list every time.


Use "Bookmark open tabs" action.

Shift+Shift
Type "Bookmark open tabs"
[Optional] add a shortcut to this action by pressing Alt+Enter
Call the action


No, that works only when i want to add the tabs to a new list.  I want to add to an existing list.  Please see the attached screenshot in the updated question.

Please subscribe to the corresponding ticket https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IJPL-121200 to follow the updates

Thank you, That ticket's state shows fixed and available in 2022.3.  I use 2023.3.4 and i can clearly see that as not available in my version.  Is it an old issue that just got re-introduced?

I see that you opened a new ticket which is linked to 121200.  I will subscribe for updates.  Thanks.
